# Кому-то, да интересен

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*И он всё-таки кому-то, да интересен.*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая, и почему? Поиском именно такой пример не нашла, а обобщить до соответствия правилу - не могу.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**И он всё-таки кому-то да интересен.**

[**ДА**, частица](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%B0)
**6.** *Усилительная.* Употребляется внутри предложения **перед сказуемым** или группой сказуемого для усиления их значения.
*В механике и я чего-нибудь **да стою*** (И. Крылов. Ларчик).
*Обязательно, о чем его ни спроси, — он всегда что-нибудь **да знает*** (А. Гайдар. Школа).

Простое предложение, сказуемое *интересен* (краткое прилагательное) — перед усилительной частицей запятая не требуется.

*И вправду странно, обычно после выхода из игры я непременно кому-то **да нужен**, а тут на тебе – никто даже не позвонил, никто не обозначился* (А. Васильев).

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ!

Answer (score 1):

В выражении *"кому-то да интересен/пригодится/нравится"* запятую не ставят. По-видимому, частица *"да"* в нём означает *"и".*

Comment: Это не союз, усилительная частица. Кому-то интересен.

Comment: Ой, промахнулся. :(

Comment: А насчёт того, что означает "и", я тоже ошибся?

Comment: Он кому-то и подойдёт? Так не говорят.

Comment: @Niemand: не говорят, хорошо, но смысл не такой передаётся, по-Вашему?

Comment: Так откуда ж я знаю, если так не говорят?! )

Comment: Так говорят, например: «Отзыв: Шампунь Concept Blond Explosion Anti-Yellow - **Кому-то и подойдет**» [http://otzovik.com/review_785636.html]. Или вот из книги "Самая очаровательная и привлекательная" (ну какие нашёл с ходу, такие и привожу тексты, простите): «Если женщинам, которые стали уже хорошими добытчицами, хочется иметь свою семью, то пример львов может **кому-то и подойдет**» .